# Efficient way to get most recent of many transaction nodes connected to a single account node by date

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I have a large number of nodes representing accounts, which we could label as say `(a :Account)`. Each `(:Account)` can have potentially tens of thousands of `(t :Transaction)` nodes connected to it, each representing the data for a transaction that occurred involving that account.

The `(:Transaction)` nodes have a `date` property. Given a date to query on what would be the most efficient way to get the *latest* `(:Transaction)` node for each `(a :Account)` that occurs before or on the query date? This could be one way to do it:

```c
// run for all address nodes
match (a :Address)
with distinct a
optional match (a)-->(t :Transaction)
where t.timestamp <= date("2014-03-07")
with a, t
where t.date = max(t.date)
return a, t
```

However I'm not sure if this method is very efficient when the number of `(t)` connected to each `(a)` becomes very large. Is there a way to write the query or to index the database such that the query time scales linearly with the number of accounts, no matter the number of transactions connected to those account nodes?

*For disclosure I posted a version of this question on the [neo4j community forum](https://community.neo4j.com/t/get-most-recent-of-000s-of-transaction-nodes-t-connected-to-a-single-account-node-a/5553), but I'm hoping the greater traffic on this site gives this question more exposure.*

Comment: Your query will only return the result for a single `Account` (or, since you used `OPTIONAL`, perhaps a null `Account`). Did you want the result for **every** `Account` (that has an matching transaction)?

Comment: Hi @cybersam - yes sorry I should have mentioned. I do want to run it for all addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In neo4j 3.5, a new ["index-backed order by"](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/query-tuning/cypher-index-values-order/#_index_backed_order_by) optimization was added. This means that if you create a "native" index (see [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.5/performance/index-configuration/schema-indexes/) for the details), then the index will be stored in sorted order, and the `ORDER BY` clause on a property on which the index is used won't actually have to do any sorting.

So, assuming that you have created in index on `:Transaction(timestamp)`, like so:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Transaction(timestamp);
```

then, in neo4j 3.5+, this query (with an optional hint to use that index) should avoid any sorting when finding the `Transaction` with the maximum `timestamp` for each `Address`:

```
MATCH (a:Address)-->(t:Transaction)
USING INDEX t:Transaction(timestamp)
WHERE t.timestamp <= date("2014-03-07")
WITH a, t
ORDER BY t.timestamp DESC
RETURN a, COLLECT(t)[0] AS transaction
```

This query should do the following:

1. Use the index to get all `Transaction` nodes with an appropriate `timestamp` (in descending order, without sorting).
2. Get the `Address` nodes related to each `Transaction`.
3. For each distinct `Address` node, create a list of all the related `Transaction` nodes (in descending `timestamp` order, without sorting), and get the first one from the list.
4. Return each distinct `Address` node and its most recent appropriate `Transaction` node.

This query will scale linearly with the number of appropriate *`Transactions`*. If your use case permits it, you could get faster results by reducing the number of  appropriate `Transactions` by also putting a lower bound in your `WHERE` clause.